# Validación de campos en R STUDIO

Tags: r, rstudio

Mi pregunta es sencilla, sin embargo no he podido encontrar la solución.

Necesito contar las observaciones de una columna que tengan una condición en relación a los caractéres.

Ejemplo: La columna código de producto está conformada por códigos de máx dos caracteres. Quisiera contar el número de observaciones que tengan menos o más de dos caracteres.

Answer (score 2):

La función `nchar` crea un vector el cual cada elemento es el número de caracteres de otro vector.

En este ejemplo el data.frame `datos` contiene al vector `producto`:

```
  producto
1      emo
2      gor
3      pdw
4       gc
5      coq
6      fkr
7      tla
8      gsz
9       kj

nchar(datos$producto)

[1] 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 2
```

Si quieres contar cuantos elementos del vector tienen cada largo puedes usar `table`. Algo así:

```
> table(nchar(datos$producto))

2 3 
2 7
```

Hay dos cadenas con 2 caracteres y 7 cadenas con 3 elementos.

Si necesitas una respuesta más específica quizás sea necesario que especifiques mejor la pregunta y agregues un ejemplo de tus datos y resultado esperado.